# How can I detect if an image is of poor quality?

Tags: image-processing, image, machine-learning

I need to filter out blurry or otherwise bad quality images from a set. I would like an efficient method to detect images that have any of the following three attributes:

1. Out of focus or motion blur
2. Lens occlusions: particles (hair or dust), smudges or hand/fingers over the lens
3. Poorly lighted over or under exposed images.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry

Comment: I think an optimal solution will likely consider the "circle of confusion" in an out-of-focus image.

Comment: Can you post a couple of samples to play with?  Have you tried a `GradientFilter`?

Comment: Also, just to be nitpicky :) [This image](http://ih2.redbubble.net/image.12764968.9301/flat,550x550,075,f.u3.jpg) is in fact very much out of focus.  Now I really do wonder how cameras evaluate focus based on the recorded image.

Comment: @Szabolcs A perfect illustration of the point I hoped to make: you can't simply look at edge contrast of the exposed image.

Comment: Sample images would really help. What about images that are in focus but blurred from a shaking camera?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Then again, it could be a photograph of a photograph, in which case it would be very much in focus.

Comment: @Szabolcs they don't. They do it using optical phase difference detection. When you only have information about the image, and not the optics and the scene (plus feedback in real time), the task becomes a lot more difficult. Cheaper cameras that just do contrast detection do indeed get stuck looking at scenes like this one.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I meant contrast detection.  I know how the "phase detect" autofocus works.  I've never used an advanced camera that uses contrast detection though.  Is it really just looking at contrast and nothing else?

Comment: This problem is discussed in some detail [here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry]

Comment: @Robert That Q&A is already linked at the very top of these comments.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think this is probably a proprietary detail for each camera manufacturer, but I expect that in practice they look at the differential contrast for several spatial frequencies rather than absolute contrast.

Comment: You could probably use a convolutional neuronal network to classify the images (or random sampled parts of larger images). I would assume that such a network would learn some kind of gradient filters in the first layers and build up logic from there.

Comment: Wow, the scope of the question has been dramatically increased with the last edit...

Comment: @Rahul As Rahul says, the last edit increased the scope of this question tremendously and imho some sort of machine learning technique is your best guess at solving this.

Comment: I think this is conundrum as my image processing experience.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As was correctly noted in comments, out-of-focus images cannot been correctly detected by a simple gradient filter since out-of-focus images *can* have sharp edges. I propose another simple idea to detect such images.

### Introduction

Roughly speaking, the brightness of a defocused image $B(x,y)$ is a convolution of a focused image $B_0(x',y')$ with some kernel $K$
$$
B(x,y) = \int K(x-x',y-y')B_0(x',y')dx\,dy.
$$

Typically, $K$ is something like [`DiskMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiskMatrix.html) in Mathematica. However, pixel values [nonlinearly](http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/dslr/Curves.html) depend on brightness (or exposure) because of the logarithmic scale in the following figure

[image]

Therefore, the real brightness exponentially depends on the pixel value $V(x,y)$. The exponential function is nonlinear so the defocusing is not a convolution in terms of $V(x,y)$. However, the exponential function grows very fast so we can approximately write

$$
V(x,y) = \max_{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2<r^2} V_0(x',y').
$$

So defocusing is rather [`Dilation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dilation.html) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)#Grayscale_dilation)) than     [`ImageConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageConvolve.html). Indeed, dilated image looks like real out of focus image.

[image]

Dilation has an interesting property: there is no sharp local maximums of pixel values. All local maximums cover some area (circle with radius $r$ at least). There is an appropriate function [`MaxDetect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxDetect.html). It gives:

[image]

There is a lot of tiny areas in the focused images and only big areas in the defocused image.

### Filter

Thus, we can introduce a simple out-of-focus measure, which is based on `MaxDetect` and `ComponentMeasurements` (these default values of `thr` and `q` is better then `thr=0.15` and `q=0.9` which I used in the first revision)

```
outOfFocus[img_Image, thr_: 0.05, q_: 0.8] := 
   Quantile[ComponentMeasurements[#, "Area"][[All, 2]]/
      ComponentMeasurements[#, "PerimeterLength"][[All, 2]], q] &@MaxDetect[img, thr];
```

### Tests

Some test images

```
imgs = {
   lena = ExampleData@{"TestImage", "Lena"},
   pentagon = ExampleData@{"AerialImage", "Pentagon"},
   park = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoXDo.jpg",
   city1 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOH7V.jpg",
   city2 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0yMA.jpg",
   city3 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCOpK.jpg"};

lena
```

[image]

```
pentagon
```

[image]

```
park
```

[image]

```
city1
```

[image]

```
city2
```

[image]

```
city3
```

[image]

Results

```
outOfFocus /@ imgs
```

[image]

Out of focus images have bigger values, so you can introduce some threshold around 0.8. `outOfFocus` works fine with artificial blurring and dilation as well

```
Plot[{Unevaluated@outOfFocus@Blur[lena, r], 
  Unevaluated@outOfFocus@Dilation[lena, DiskMatrix@r]}, {r, 0, 4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Blur", "Dilation"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "outOfFocus"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's nice to have you actively posting again. :-)

Comment: The present code is rather slow.  [This](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Out_of_Focus_Green_Backgounds-16.jpg) large image took 24 seconds to process.  How might one optimize this?

Comment: Although it displays depth of field [this image](http://thelearningcurve.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Out-Of-Focus.jpg) would not generally be considered out of focus yet your function returns a value of `4.98737`.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard one may downsample large images provided it is not done to such an extent as to degrade the contrast at high spatial frequencies. I also disagree about the second image; the majority of it is in fact out of focus, even if the focal point is included in the scene.

Comment: @Oleksandr (1) Downsampling is problematic I think as one usually has to view images at full size when manually looking for OOF images as at smaller size problems are easily hidden.  (2) Yes, but this depth-of-field is common in artistic photography therefore if the function is to be of wide applicability it needs to discriminate DOF from OOF. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Some times I have a lot of work, sometimes I have a lot of spare time. I'm glad to participate in our community when I able to do it. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard *Big images:* one can check downsampled image, then some randomly picked pieces. *DOF:* your image is very bright so it is difficult to find local maximums. [This one](https://library.creativecow.net/articles/terry_todd/depth_of_field_converters/gnome-dof.JPG) gives `0.9`, which is close to values of focused images. Anyway, there are many possibilities to tune parameters and optimize algorithm. No other algorithms which I tried, couldn't distinguish `city1` and `city3` :-)

Comment: @ybeltukov I like the idea of checking a random sampling for focus; how large would the sections need to be for the algorithm to be effective?  By the way I already voted for this fine answer; my questions are only intended for possible refinement.  I think for many uses it is important to handle the DOF images well.  Perhaps there could be a parameter that relates to the proportion of the image that needs to be in focus; maybe this could even be integrated with the sampling idea.

Comment: Here is another image to test with: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Josefina_with_Bokeh.jpg -- I get `1.8762` with the default parameters.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for the interesting test images! The maximum fraction of blurred area is already implicitly in the parameters `thr` and `q`. Maybe `thr=0.05` and `q=0.8` is [better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4JS2U.png) for detecting OOF and not DOF for all images except "bubbles" (which is too artificial).

Comment: I'm not sure this jives with the [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry) they seem to think the laplacian method is better, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Also, (this would be super helpful) is there a list of the opencv equivalents of Mathematica's functions Quantile, ComponentMeasurements[#, "Area"]&, ComponentMeasurements[#,"PerimeterLength"]&, and MaxDetect?

Comment: @M.R. Laplacian method isn't good for real images. It gives [random results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3JKSv.png). FFT method is [better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EfxO4.png). However FFT gives wrong results for images with big low-contrast areas (e.g. sky).

Comment: @M.R. The main point is to find local maxima (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550290/find-local-maxima-in-grayscale-image-using-opencv)). Then you can analyse pixel values in $n\times n$ region around each maximum and measure how pixels with brightness $[q_{\rm max}-\delta,q_{\rm max}]$ form big filled area in each region.