# Restoring an out of focus image

Tags: image-processing

Folks,

I am studying ways to deblurring an image:

Sample: [image: decadence], an my goal is the money in that hand. Is possible improve the image, features, etc..?

I tried all the de blurring methods:

1 - first  I cropped the image: [image: cropped decadence];

2 - I tried a lot of codes:

```
ImageDeconvolve[imag2, GaussianMatrix[2], 
   Method -> #] & /@ {"DampedLS", "Tikhonov", "TSVD", "Wiener"}


ImageDeconvolve[imag2, GaussianMatrix[2], 
   Method -> {#, "Preconditioned" -> False}, 
   MaxIterations -> 100] & /@ {"Hybrid", "SteepestDescent", 
  "RichardsonLucy"}



ImageDeconvolve[imag2, GaussianMatrix[2], 
   Method -> {#, "Preconditioned" -> True}] & /@ {"Hybrid", 
  "SteepestDescent", "RichardsonLucy"}
```

etc... In fact, I use all the  examples in: [ImageDeconvolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html)

And My best result was:

```
Sharpen[imag2, 10]
```

[image: decadence3]

Which codes can be applied  and do better results (if possible, of course..)?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71726/7167)

Comment: Yes, but that question shows how much is an image out of focus.

Comment: Lenses are not designed to perform optimally when not focused. Astigmatism, coma, and chromatic aberrations will all be evident in an unfocused image, so it is necessary to deconvolve with respect to the point spread function from a physical model of the lens (not just e.g. a Gaussian) to produce a focused image. Additionally it appears that your sensor is not sampling the image finely enough, or the sensor is not properly calibrated (as we see from the pixellation in the deconvolved result), and there are objects at different depths in the image. This is a very difficult problem.

Comment: I will add to Oleksandr's comment that you appear to be working with a jpeg image, so a lot of information will have been discarded by the compression algorithm. I suspect it will be impossible to get anything much better than your `Sharpen` result.

Comment: Ok, So, It it would be necessary use psf as we do in astrometry or astrophotography, evaluting the MMS for the image, using a default image for that lens for determining the constants of that lens, for compensating aberrations and another errors that cause the distorsions.

Comment: Yes, definitely. But scientific cameras typically are linear and record at 14 bits resolution or higher. Another issue is that the contrast of the given image looks blown out and it does not appear to have been recorded at high quantization depth. As such it is entirely possible that the information needed to reconstruct the focused image is simply not present in the available data even if you were to completely characterize the optics.

Comment: @locometro, or maybe it is not money but some white papers, so it will not be possible to see them anyway. More seriously, did you try to exploit the fact that you know more or less where the focus is? Also, do you know, what kind of money might it be? Recognising and image out of ten possibilities might go easier than resolving the whole image.

Comment: Good points. The related question , mentioned by   bobthechemist , is a good start, isn it?

Comment: Surprinsingly, I discovered that image was taken from another image in a notebook screen... So one more time , the power of mathematica code has shown itself again!! As soon as I get the primary image I post it again here.